# Setting WPF Style Trigger removes Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF DataGridCheckBoxColumn, which is bound to an object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged as shown below:

```
DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCheckBoxCellStyle}"/>
```

Here is the associated object:

```
public class ListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    private bool isSelected = false;
    public bool IsSelected { get { return isSelected; } set { isSelected = value; OnChanged("IsSelected"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected, except that in order to set the Checkbox to Checked, I need to double click, in order to first select the column, and then set the checkbox value.

So, I decide to implement a Style trigger as shown below:

```
<Style x:Key="MyDataGridCheckBoxCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now I am able to single click to Check the Checkbox, but my binding doesn't work anymore. Any idea of what is going on here? Why does setting the Style Trigger remove the binding?

Comment: You are overriding the default style for the DataGridCell. Try to add BasedOn={StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}.

Comment: Another way would be to use a DataGridTemplateColumn and set a CheckBox as Template (not EditingTemplate), instead of setting the style.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen, I tried your suggestion. Now when I move the mouse away from the checkbox, it automatically gets unchecked. I am guessing this is because the underlying object was not updated.

Comment: You are also replacing the entire triggers collection on the style. So that might cause some erratic behaviour. You can find the DataGridCell template from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28v=vs.95%29.aspx.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen, apologise if this is a stupid question, it's my first WPF project. Does this mean I need to essentially copy in the entire template, and only modify the bits I need modified? Is there any way to inherit and just change one element?

Comment: That depends on what you are doing, but if you need to make something of your own and expect the custom behaviour to still apply, be prepared to copy the style and modify where you need to.

Comment: You could try this http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing

Comment: @JanneMatikainen, your link worked like a charm! Thank you, I am still trying to wrap my head around modifying templates. If you want to post it as an answer I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the style can cause some issues with the default template. You would most likely need to copy the entire style + template and then modify that to suit your needs. You could try this http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing however.

Comment: The link worked like a charm, and much easier than modifying the template.